# Reflection : How to get the result (and do foreach on it) from method invoked using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, generic-list

I would like to invoke some methods from different repository and having the same type `List<>` as result but I don't know how to cast the result without hard code and also how to use `foreach` on this result, here the example below :

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class PersonRepository
{
    public List<Person> GetPersons()
    {
          List<Person> list = new List<Person>();

          //Some processing...

          return list;
    }
}

class AnimalRepository
{
    public List<Animal> GetAnimals()
    {
        List<Animal> list = new List<Animal>();

        //Some processing...

         return list;
    }
}

public class ReflectionClass
{
    public List<T> GetResultFromMethodInvoked<T>(string entityName, string repositoryName, string methodName)
    {
        List<T> lists = new List<T>();
        Type entity_type = Type.GetType("Entities." + entityName + " ,Entities");
        Type repository = Type.GetType("Crud." + repositoryName + ", Crud");
        MethodInfo method = repository.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);


        var r= method.Invoke(repository, parameters);


        Convert.ChangeType(r, typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { entity_type }));

        lists = (List<T>)r;

        return lists;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReflectionClass reflection = new ReflectionClass();
        /* Should have List<Person> as RESULT */
        reflection.GetResultFromMethodInvoked("Person", "PersonRepository", "GetPersons");

        /* Should have List<Animal> as RESULT */
        reflection.GetResultFromMethodInvoked("Animal", "AnimalRepository", "GetAnimals");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible, you can´t let the **compiler** infer a type that you provide at **runtime**. You have o provide the generic type-argument at **compile**-time to use strong typing.

Comment: However you can of course cast your result to the non-generic `IEnumerable`-interface and iterate this. Or create an interface that all your possible types within the list implement and cast to `List<TheInterface>`.

Comment: Hi @HimBromBeere, I am not sure to understand good, I am new in C#, just could you please give me an example for what you mentioned ? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use generics `public List<T> GetResultFromMethodInvoked<T>(string entityName, string repositoryName, string methodName)` so:

```
ReflectionClass reflection = new ReflectionClass();
/* Should have List<Person> as RESULT */
List<Person> result = reflection.GetResultFromMethodInvoked<Person>("Person", "PersonRepository", "GetPersons");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do this as the compiler as no knowledge that your **runtime**-string `"Person"` means the `Person`-type. You can´t expect the compiler to infer a type provided at runtime (e.g. via its name).

So you have three options.

1. You allready mentioned this, cast to the actual list-type, e.g. `List<Person>`.
2. alternativly let all your types that your list may contain inherit from a common interface and cast to a list of the interface-type

   ```
   interface MyInterface
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   class Person : MyInterface
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   class Animal : MyInterface
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Now use the interface for your list:

   ```
   var result = reflection.GetResultFromMethodInvoked<MyInterface>("Person", "PersonRepository", "GetPersons");
   foreach(var o in result) 
       Console.WriteLine(o.Name);
   ```
3. omit strong typing at all and go with the non-generic `Enumerable`-class and iterate this:

   ```
   var result = (Enumerable) reflection.GetResultFromMethodInvoked("Person", "PersonRepository", "GetPersons");
   foreach(var o in result) ...
   ```

   For this to work your method should of course be non-generic also, as you can´t really use the generic type anyway outside that method.

Comment: @AbdelatifLatrach As I allready said a geeric type-argument (that is something within brackets, either `(MyType) result` or DoSomething<MyType>()` is a *compile*-time information. Providing a typename as string is however a runtime-information, which means it is evaluated when you actually *execute* your program. So short answr is: no, this isn´t possible.